# How to insert button into Table view cell Swift

Tags: swift

How do add button on each cell for table view cell so that it know which one is from.

**Example:**

Data have 2 products which is product A and product B, then I store them in array which is [product]. Inside the array, there have their detail which are name and price. So, I have successful making these into the table view. 
The Question is how to insert button into the table view cell?

**Example:**

When button pressed, it know which row is pressed which is when press the 2nd row will be product B.
I'm newbie here. Need help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Option one - easy, quick, bad:

create instance of the `UIButton` with the frame to position where you actually want the button to be placed. add `tag` property as well as the action. Action would be the same for the each button and you could use that tag to do the different actions.

Option two:

Create subclass of your UITableViewCell. Add all the element you want there. Create action for the button and you can set the target `UITableViewCell` or `UITableViewController`. If you choose `UITableViewCell` to be the target you will have to implement delegate, confront that delegate in the `UITableViewController` and implement that delegate function there. If you choose controller to be the target, you will have to send it to the cell. You will have to set tag as well.

I would use option two because it is scalable, easly maintained, and you have visual of the cell. Adding more components is easier as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing you need to put button or any other control in `UITableViewCell` to identify the selected cell.

All you need to do, is to implement following delegate method in to your class where you have implemented `UITableView`

```
tableView(_:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:)
tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)
```

and these methods will let you know selected `UITableViewCell` `indexPath` and you can do what you want to do on selection.

**Note:** do not forget to set your `UIViewController` as **delegate** to `UITableView` (almost like you did in case of `DataSource`).

Here's a [Github](https://github.com/suryakants/CustomTableViewCellWithSwift.git) repo you can refer, the code is not in good shape though.